# Local variable reference and GC when passing member to new Thread as argument

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand, at a fundamental level, what will happen to the local variable being passed to the thread in the following situation.  I need a cleanup action to happen on `someObject` which has a `delete` method, which calls an external API to delete the instance of someObject by its member, `id`.

```
public interface Deleteable {
    public delete() 
}

public SomeClass implements Deleteable {
    int id;
    public void delete() {
        HttpApiCall.deleteById(this.id);
    }
}

SomeClass someObject = null;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
// simple loop to illustrate problem
    someObject = new SomeClass();
    Runtime.getRuntime()
    .addShutdownHook(new Thread(someObject::delete));
}
```

While the program is executing, will some of the instances of SomeClass be GC'ed before the thread will be able to call delete?  Will each thread receive their own copy that was newed or will the operate on the last set value of `someObject`?

I read up a little bit about the `volatile` keyword but I am not sure it is going to help me here.

Comment: How serious is it if the shutdownhook doesn't get called? Because that's possible.

Comment: Could you explain further about in what situations the shutdownhook would not be called?

Comment: It's all in the javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You are adding these `someObject::delete` method references to a collection in `Runtime`. Since the `Runtime` is still reachable, these objects too are reachable and shouldn't get GCd.

Comment: Not to mention that it's referenced from an unstarted thread, making even *more* sure it's not eligible for GC.